# Embed html in AutoCAD

Tags: html, autocad, autolisp

Does anyone know of a way to embed html into Autocad? I want to be able to click on an object and a window within Autocad pop-up with some pictures and text in a table. I'm hoping there's a way that looks similar to a Google earth kml when the description shows?

Comment: Have you explored adding hyperlinks to objects?

Comment: Yes, but it opens a web browser each time which would work but is a bit messy plus I would have to send the html files and images with the drawing. I was hoping there might be a way to embed the html within the dwg and possibly reference the images

Comment: Use xrecords to store hyperlinks on objects.  Add an event handler to display a form and use the xrecord data.

Comment: @Miiir thanks, I'm not familiar with those methods but I'll look into them and let you know how I do

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is possible. Autocad can be driven by Javascript meanwhile. And by that you can create own palettes which are in fact a chrome browser window which seamless integrates in the Acad application. You can nearly reach the full acad API from Javascript. And its also possible to extend the JS API by own routines as well. So you will be able to use the native links inside the drawing as well as any own Xdata or Dictionarys as well.
[Getting started with Autocad Javascript](https://df-prod.autocad360.com/jsapi/v3/GettingStart/index.html?url=files/GUID-140C1DFD-D9CC-4856-8C8D-54B6B3BA8544.htm,topicNumber=d30e415)|[Enhance ACAD JS API by .NET](https://www.keanw.com/2013/05/complementing-autocads-javascript-api-using-net.html)| [Updated JS API Reference](https://www.keanw.com/2014/04/autocad-2015s-updated-javascript-api.html)